# The error of ".post is not a function" with mongoose at Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I made an router at nodejs express with Mongoose.

When I send `const { clientID, orderID } = req.body;` by Postman,

`await matching.save();`  is working well.
But after that it makes an error like below.

How can I solve this problem?

> TypeError: matching.post is not a function
> at router.post (D:\Dev\matching\matching\routes\match ing.js:24:20)
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const Matching = require("./../models/matching");

function wait(time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time);
  });
}

router.post("/orderpost", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { clientID, orderID } = req.body;
    const listOn = true;

    const matching = new Matching({
      clientID,
      orderID,
      listOn
    });

    await matching.save();

    await matching.post("save", (doc, next) => {
      wait(3000).then(() => {
        console.log("good");
        next();
      });
    });

    res.send("good");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

I added Schema model also.
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

```
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const MatchingSchema = new Schema({
  clientID: String,
  riderID: [String],
  orderID: String,
  listOn: Boolean
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Matching", MatchingSchema);
```

Comment: what is your `Matching`, is it `Schema` or `Model`, looks like the later, could you post the code in `models/matching` as well

Comment: I attached that, Thank you so much for your attention!

Answer (score 2):

`post` method is available to `Schema` not `Model`. It should be called on your schema.

```
MatchingSchema.post("save", (doc) => {
  console.log("good");
});
```

Also you don't need to call `wait` (not sure why you're doing it). It's called only after `save` is executed.

From [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post):

> `post` middleware are executed after the hooked method and all of its pre middleware have completed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one question more. How can I read Schema from the other .js file? Bcz I imported model of schema from the other path. Must I put schema inside of router.js.?

Comment: You could put the post hook in your `matching` file where you define the schema.